# Can you fix a corrupted 7z file?

Tags: 7-zip, archiving

So, I had a cd, with a scratch on it. The cd contained a 7z file. When I try to copy the file it gave me an error, so I used corrupted disk repair fixer and I managed to open the 7z, and view the directory structure, but when I try to copy a file from it, winrar opens a window and  a few thousand errors pop up, and the file doesn't get copied. I tried all the archive fixers that I could find, but all were for zip or rar. Is there any way to fix the archive, even if I can't recover all the files in it?

Comment: Repair the cd is you best chance, a professional polish job, some have used clear fingernail polish in deep scratches to repair ones that cannot be polished out, seek professional repair if the data is valuable.